# Qubole: How can I download scheduler result in python?

Tags: python, qubole

Like title, I managed myself download the Qubole result using the query id in python, however, is there a method that I can download the result using scheduler job ID instead of query ID?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python package named `requests` to access [Scheduler API](http://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/rest-api/scheduler_api/index.html)

I'm still unsure if my code is using the best practice of python since I still use hard-coded phrase `per_page=1000000` which will GET 1000000 result per page per request

```
url = 'https://api.qubole.com/api/v1.2/scheduler/{}/actions?per_page=1000000'.format(id)
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'X-AUTH-TOKEN': '<YOUR-TOKEN>'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

json_object=[json.dumps(r.get('actions'))]
jsonRDD = sc.parallelize(json_object)
df = spark.read.json(jsonRDD)
```

the result of your scheduler should be on column `command.status`